# Display the clipboard information in a ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, clipboard

I am having a requirement to show the data in the clipboard to the readable control.
The clipboard data may be text,document or any type. the control should display the information.

Is there any controls available in ASP.net

This is client side clipboard

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to create and embed a Silverlight 2 control into your webpage. With the correct security setting this should allow you access to the clip board indirectly.

[Storing text in the clipboard using Silverlight 2](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2008/05/clipboard-access/)

[Getting Started with Silverlight 2](http://silverlight.net/GetStarted/)

[Helpful Blog tutorial on getting started](http://jesseliberty.com/2008/03/18/tip-of-the-day-getting-started-with-silverlight-2/)

Answer (score 1):

Which clipboard are you talking about?

The server-side clipboard or the client side clipboard (I assume it to be client side).

From what I know, if you just want to display the info about what is held in clipboard - javascript has Clipboard object that you can use. It might have security constraints (As you are trying to access client side clipboard)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way that the server can possibly read from the client's clipboard. So if you mean what the **user** has in their clipboard (at the server): it can't be done. You might be able to do some things with javascript, but then ASP.NET becomes largely irrelevant as a detail.

Alternatively, put it this way: have you ever seen this done?

Normally, to get a web-site to do something with non-text data, you need to use a file/upload control (Browse...) to send the data to the server. You might want to investigate this option.

If you need more power at the client, consider Silverlight, Flash, ClickOnce, etc (but try to avoid OCX - that is a dead technology).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to embed a .NET Windows Forms user control in a web page. Using this you might be able to access the clipboard to make the data available to your web page.

I'm not sure if this would work, for the user control will run with very limited rights, but it could be worth a try.